# Access to on-premises APIs with Azure AD Application Proxy: login works but requests with token return ms login site html

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, reverse-proxy

i am trying to configure what is described in this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/application-proxy-secure-api-access). The login works without a problem but when i try to request anything from my API the request returns the html code of the microsoft login page.
Additionally i tried to do the request with postman but that didn´t work either.

As scopes i defined "user.read" and the identifier of my enterprise application as described in the article. (the textbox where you configure that your app regestration has the rights to access the API)

Any guess what i might be missing here?

best regards
Chris

Comment: The problem: possibly there is an issue with the token, that's why AADAP proxy service redirects the client to login.microsoftonline.com. Can you raise a support ticket ? We could look into this.

Comment: Hello, I have same problem, Did you find a solution please ? thanks.